# Get the user to accept Terms & Conditions when signing up with OAuth

Tags: forms, web, signup-signon, authentication

The register form I'm working on allows the user to sign up using their Facebook account or to create a new account by typing their email and password. Here a mockup:

[image]

Currently, clicking on the Facebook button (and authenticating via the Facebook pop-up) redirects them automatically to the next page in the sign up flow. However, this means that the user can sign up without explicitly accepting the terms and conditions of the page.

I'm looking for the best way to "force" the user to accept the terms and conditions when using OAuth. Some options I thought about:

- Clicking on the "Use Facebook" button marks the Terms checkbox as invalid (if unchecked) and doesn't proceed unless it's checked — *feels awkward because the checkbox visually belongs to the fields that can be skipped when using OAuth (email, password)*
- Add a second Terms checkbox right below the Facebook button and use the same idea — *having two checkboxes on the page seems unnecessary*
- After successful login via Facebook, replace the Email and Password fields with some information about the Facebook account of the user and let them register using the Sign Up bottom on the bottom of the page (and validate the checkbox) — *increases the actions needed to create an account and would require big changes in our backend*
- Show a pop-up asking the user to accept the Terms and then proceed to Facebook authentication — *probably the best idea so far, but I'd like to avoid using multiple pop-ups*

Does anyone have a better idea? Unfortunately we can't use a generic "By signing up you automatically accept our terms ..." text because of GDPR (the user has to consent manually).

Comment: IMO your last option makes the most sense

Answer (score 0):

Is there an explicit reason why Facebook is first and Sign up with email second? If not, your best bet might be to swop the two around. Doing so, will allow you to group the two buttons "Sign up" and "Sign up with Facebook" closer together. "I accept the terms and conditions" can then live below the second button and visually and conceptually apply to both. The user should not be able to proceed with either of the two actions, without first accepting the terms and conditions.

Also, I understand that this might be a low fidelity mock-up, but ensure that the terms & conditions checkbox copy does not elipse (...) - rather have it wrap to the next line. And be sure to add a link to the words "terms and conditions" to enable users to read through them before actively accepting.

Answer (score 0):

So no matter how they decide to sign up you need them to accept the T&C?

Easiest solution is to put the "Accept T&C" checkbox at the top separated from either option visually and disable both sign up buttons until the checkbox is selected.

You could also have the Facebook or Username/Password options be radio buttons, with a single "Create Account" button under the Accept T&C that will direct them appropriately to the next step.